# Desktop cube doesn't work

Tags: unity, compiz, cube

I remembered that using the desktop cube was pretty fun, back in 2010, but I haven't used it since.

Upon enabling it in the CompizConfig Settings Manager, I was informed that its keybindings conflict with the ones of other plugins. I always chose to disable the other plugin or the keybinding of the other plugin so that the check mark at `Desktop Cube` got set.

Its keybinding to unfold the cube (`Unfold Cube Key`) was set to `<Control><Alt>Down` by default. However, when pressing it, nothing happened. I then also set the check mark of `Rotate Cube`, just to be sure. But still, nothing happened when pressing the key combination. Not even after restarting my machine.

I then set it to several other key combinations but they don't work either.

My laptop runs Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit with the `4.4.0-59-generic` kernel. The graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M and uses the free drivers:

> Using X.Org X server – Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

No proprietary drivers are used. Unity is in version 7.4.0 and CompizConfig Settings Manager is in version 0.9.12.2, according to the GUI. `compiz --version` prints `Compiz 0.9.12.2`.

My question – of course – is: How do I get the desktop cube to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, Compiz and the desktop cube are relatively dead now. The cube itself seems to have been [last updated](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~compiz-team/compiz/0.9.13/files/head:/plugins/) in 2015. Doesn't bode well.

Comment: Cube & rotate cube work fine in 16.04 inc. the default bindings. The cube plugin only has 1 binding & should not produce a conflict pop up when enabling. The rotate cube plugin has 1 conflict, 'rotate to face1' which should be left as is. If you were getting other conflicts than just that single  one you should note exactly what it or they were. Maybe reset back to defaults & try again. see - http://askubuntu.com/questions/620947/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration-on-15-04  , use 1st answer (12 votes)